# Fixed table layout, with controlled column widths that scales

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to show a html table with five columns. The first should be 100px wide, the next two should be flexible and the last two should be 200px. The table should not get horizontal scroll, instead shrink columns and hide overflowing text (in both header and body cells) when there is not enough space available. Something like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px">First column</th>
      <th>Second column</th>
      <th>Third column</th>
      <th style="width: 200px">Fourth column</th>
      <th style="width: 200px">Fifth column</th>
    </tr>
  </th>
  ...body...
</table>
```

If the available space for the table is **800px**, then the columns should get the following withs: `[100px, 150px, 150px, 200px, 200px]` (distributing the extra 300 on the two fluid columns)

However, if there is not enough space to fill out the given sizes, fluid colums should have a minimum width (so they are not hidden away completely), and the other columns should scale down equally! Like if the available width where **400px** and minimum widths for fluid columns where **50px**, the columns should be `[60px, 50px, 50px, 120px, 120px]`.

I have been very close to a working solution with a lot of different attempts, including various combinations of `table-layout: fixed`, `table-layout: auto`, setting the requested widths on header cells with both `max-width` and `width`, with only `width`, setting `max-width: 0` on cells and a few other tricks. But there is always some problem, like:

- Some times, header cells won't shrink smaller than the size of the text in their cells
- Some times, body cells won't shrink smaller than the size of the text in their cells
- Some times, it grows outside the available width (making horizontal scroll for the whole table)
- Some times, cells scale down when available width is smaller, but without the ratio between the different cells with given width requirements.
- A few other strange cases.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Some examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/pLx50vqz/7/ - Seems to provide the same result in FireFox and Chrome. Fixed columns (first, fourth and fifth) has the given `width`, but it does not shrink when available space is less than the total of widths, and the two other columns (second and third) ignores min-width and shrinks when there is not enough space available.

https://jsfiddle.net/pLx50vqz/12/ - Columns shrink nicely when width is limited, but it ignores `max-width`, so columns grow larger when available width is high, and it ignores the scaling between columns (same width)

Comment: It could be nice if you could provide a [mre] of the issues you are facing. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create a runnable example here.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added a couple of examples (fifdles) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how standardized using grid-css on table-tags are, but it works better toward the desired result than all normal table-display-examples I have attempted. Any thoughts on this solution? Browser support etc..

```
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(30px, 100px) minmax(30px, 1fr) minmax(30px, 1fr) minmax(30px, 200px) minmax(30px, 200px);
}
```

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/fhcz51u7/

Answer (score 0):

This is my final answer is to Bootstrap the column with xs. The size for xs is 768px and less. It should auto adjust as needed automatically. Coding inside tables are not easy so i created the full table be ware for each th there sould be a td or it will not line up properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left";>First column</th>
      <th style="text-align: left";>Second column</th>
      <th style="text-align: left";>Third column</th>
      <th style="text-align: left";>Fourth column</th>
      <th style="text-align: left";>Fifth column</th>
    </tr>   
<tbody>
<div class="row">
        <td>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        </div>
       </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
         </td>
        <td>
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-xs-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="">
            <div class="col-xs-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-xs-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. The problem is that if you try to cut of the text (white-space: nowrap + overflow: hidden), it does not work anymore. I have added a couple of example to the original post now that show some of the close cases I had during my testing.